# Extract ECDSA non-exportable private key from x509 certificate

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, x509certificate, ecdsa

I have a x509 certificate stored in windows certificate store and it contains a ECDSA private key marked as non-exportable.

How can I retrive the private key for signing in C# with .Net framework 4.7.2?

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("StoreName", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
X509Certificate2 Cert = null;
if(store.Certificates.Count > 0)
{
Cert = store.Certificates[0];
}
                    
var CertPK = Cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey(); // return null
```

The Private key is associated with the certificate

[image]

and the public key type is as the image

[image]

Comment: If GetECDsaPrivateKey is returning null, that means either the cert has no associated private key or the public key type of the certificate isn't ECC.  It has nothing to do with exportability.

Comment: I added extra infor to the question regarding your comment  @bartonjs

Comment: You have a CNG key and the signature of the certificate uses ECDsa.  The key is not ECDsa.

Comment: If you're looking at details of the object returned by GetECDsaPrivateKey, it clearly didn't return null.  Your sample code and the debugger image don't match.

Comment: Dear @bartonjs The debugger image is for public key and I add it to respond to your first comment